# Allow Chrome to use unlimited memory

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-management

Is there any way to allow Chrome to use all the available RAM in the computer? The javascript running on the page is complex and needs a lot of memory. I would like Chrome to use as much memory as possible.
Right now, the memory spikes up to around 800 MB and then I am getting the "script on the page used too much memory. Reload to enable scripts again" warning. 
Does Chrome automatically use all the available RAM or do I need to provide some command-line argument while starting it up to allow this?
Thanks!